# Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED when I add dependency implementation 'com.mesibo.api:mesibo:1.5.2'

Tags: mesibo

I started a new project in Android Studio. Empty project compiles without problem.

As soon as I add implementation 'com.mesibo.api:mesibo:1.5.2' to dependencies, I get the following error:

```
[com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0] C:\Users\nenad\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\2321a6ddb441101d2687f6656a3ad88a\animated-vector-drawable-28.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable' used in: com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0, com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0.
[androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1] C:\Users\nenad\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\7db5a34e07a8e6159e7e1ab900eaa2f0\versionedparcelable-1.1.1\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Package name 'androidx.versionedparcelable' used in: androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1, com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0.
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\LiburnijaVoIP\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 Error:
    Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.5.0] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-22:19 to override.
```

My build.gradle is as follows:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hr.grafiknet.liburnijavoip"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.mesibo.api:mesibo:1.5.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those errors are dure to mixing AndroidX/Support. Enable jetifier to resolve. Add following lines to your `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```